# В чем выгода асинхронности, если не во времени исполнения?

Tags: c#, .net

Не могу понять, в чем профит асинхронности в .net (не ui приложения).

```
Console.WriteLine("Start Main");
await PrintAsync();   
Console.WriteLine("End Main");

void Print()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);    
    Console.WriteLine("Print");
}

async Task PrintAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start PrintAsync"); 
    await Task.Run(() => Print());             
    Console.WriteLine("End PrintAsync"); 
}
```

Я бы понял, если бы вывод был таким:

```
Start Main
Start PrintAsync
End Main
Print
End PrintAsync
```

Т.е. профит такой: main работает, дошел до долгой задачи, отдал ее другому потоку, а сам продолжил работать, после чего подхватил ответ от той долгой задачи. Поток не останавливает свою работу.
Но вывод, конечно, другой:

```
Start Main
Start PrintAsync
Print
End PrintAsync
End Main
```

Т.е. поток main все равно останавливается и ждет, пока придет ответ от асинхронной операции, отданной на сторону. Не проще ли тогда забить на асинхронность и делать все синхронно, раз все равно придется ждать?!

Comment: Вы можете присвоить таск возвращаемый PrintAsync() в переменную и await сделать в конце, после печати "end main". И поменяйте Thread.Sleep на Task.Delay

Comment: А теперь добавьте везде вывод `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` и увидите, что айдишники (скорее всего) разные, т. е. поток main освободился и мог бы выполнять другую работу, пока выполнялась асинхронная операция.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, у меня в main еще потом куча кода, но он не выполняется, пока не дождется результата await PrintAsync(). Поэтому я и спросил, в чем профит, если все равно программа стоит и ждет метод, как ждала бы его в обычном синхронном случае.

Comment: @CrazyElf т.е. профит только в том, что можно подождать в любом месте? Не понимаю, я же могу сделать все синхронно и просто вызвать метод дальше и все.

Comment: Профит в том, что реальный физический поток операционной системы _освобождается_! И может использоваться для другой работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью асинхронный код:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Start Main");
// Запускаем задачу PrintAsync и спокойно идём дальше
var printTask = PrintAsync();
Console.WriteLine("End Main");
// Ждём завершения задачи PrintAsync
await printTask;

async Task PrintDelayAsync()
{
    // Ждём 3 секунды, но при этом поток не будет занят
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Print");
}

async Task PrintAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start PrintAsync");
    // Ждём пока метод отработает, но поток не занят
    await PrintDelayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("End PrintAsync");
}
```

Весь этот код может выполняться даже одним потоком, при этом в моменты ожидания `await` этот поток освобождается может выполнять какие-то другие асинхронные задачи из вашего кода, если они у вас будут.

Пример параллельного исполнения задач:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Start Main");
await PrintAsync();
Console.WriteLine("End Main");

async Task Print1Async()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Print 1");
}

async Task Print2Async()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Print 2");
}

async Task Print3Async()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Print 3");
}

async Task PrintAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start PrintAsync");
    var tasks = new List<Task>() { Print1Async(), Print2Async(), Print3Async() };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("End PrintAsync");
}
```

Вывод:

```
Start Main
Start PrintAsync
Print 3
Print 2
Print 1
End PrintAsync
End Main
```

То есть суть в чём - запустились сразу 3 задачи, выполнились они не в том порядке, как были запущены, а где меньше задержка, та раньше и выполнилась. При этом, повторюсь, достаточно одного потока, чтобы выполнять этот код. Что очень существенно, когда речь идёт о сильно загруженных программах типа веб-сервера или какого-то обработчика данных реального времени.

Comment: Ага, т.е. профит в кол-ве свободных потоков. А в вашем примере с параллельным выполнением возможно сделать так, чтобы задачи выполнялись четко в определенном порядке вне зависимости от задержки (напр., 2-1-3)?

Comment: @NikashDjonson В чётком порядке - просто делаете задачам по очереди `await` в том порядке, в каком вам нужно )  Пока предыдущая задача не окончится, следующая не начнётся. `await Print2Async(); await Print1Async(); await Print3Async()`.